# Passing data from one view to another using UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass data from one controller to another using UI Router. I have two views populated with data from two different APIs. View 1 contains a ng-repeater with a list of restaurants from an API endpoint (returns name, image and ID). View 2 contains the restaurant information from another API endpoint (returns description, menu and ID). A user clicks on a restaurant in the View1 list and it opens that restaurant in View 2 with the description etc by passing the restaurant ID. The problem is the API endpoint in View 2 does not contain the restaurant name and image. So in order to display the name and image I had to pass them in the link like this...

```
<a ui-sref="restaurantProfile({id: restaurant.Id, name: restaurant.Name, image: restaurant.Logo[0].StandardResolutionURL})">{{restaurant.Name}}</a>
```

And then that is handeled by the controller for View 2 like this

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('components.restaurantProfile', [])
    .controller('RestaurantProfileController', function(resolvedRestaurantId, Restaurants, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.name =  $stateParams.name;
        vm.image = $stateParams.image;

        Restaurants.findByRestaurantId(resolvedRestaurantId)
            .then(function(result) {
                vm.restaurant = result
            })
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('restaurantProfile', {
                url: '/restaurant/:id',
                templateUrl: 'components/restaurant-profile/View2.html',
                controller: 'RestaurantProfileController as pc',
                params: {
                    name: '',
                    image: ''
                },
                resolve: {
                    resolvedRestaurantId: function($stateParams) {
                        return $stateParams.id;
                    }
                }
            });
    });
})();
```

This works, but it doesnt feel right. Especially if I need to pass more params, the ui-sref link would become very long. Is there a better way to pass the name/image from the selected restuarant in View1 to View2? Is it possible to pass the selected restaurant object from the repeater to another view?

**Also**, if it helps, the service called `Restaurants` which is injected into `RestaurantProfileController` above is also shared with View1 controller. Could I pass it through there?

Apologies for the long post - I wanted to make sure I was clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you populating the entire details of hotel while listing in View1? I would suggest you bring the meta details(just the required details for listing) and get the full details in View2 by calling an api for the given hotel id; just a suggestion.

If you need to pass the entire details from View1 to View2, then use a service to handle this; assign hotel details to an object in your service and access that object in View2-Service being singleton, you will get that details in View2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd rather not do another API call as I want to keep server requests to a minimum. If using $stateParams is not the best option for this, I will create a service to share that object.

Comment: @Josethehose - multiple server requests (lazy loading) vs loading entire details in one go (greedy loading) depends upon your business needs. Say, you have 25 hotels listed and you are sure that the user will check the details for atleast half of those hotels, then getting the entire details (greedy loading) makes sense. But on the other hand, if the chances of user visiting the hotel details are on the lower side, then I would go for lazy loading. Just a thought!

Comment: Cool - thanks again. Something to think about